# Calling a method which return Int32 within a foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I seek your help with understanding following in MVC 5. I have read a number of previous posts but I did not get answer I needed.

I have Store which has many items, but the items can be different types. I want to show a table of all the Stores in the Store/Index view with each Store and its count of different item types.

e.g. (layout is just for simplicity and clarity)
Store-----#A-----#B-----#C
Alder-----10-----22-----43
Birmh-----07-----11-----89
etc.

As well as Store and Item models I have a StoreDetails ViewModel which contains Storename and counts.

In Store/Index controller I build a List of StoreDetails to be passed to Store/Index view.

To calculate the counts I am doing the following in Store/Index controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = db.Stores
                      .OrderBy(s => s.StoreName)
                      .Select(s => new StoreDetails
                                   {
                                       ID = s.ID,
                                       Name = s.StoreName,
                                       CountOfItems = s.Items.Count(),
                                       CountOfBigType = BigCount(s.ID)
                                       //other counts if i can get this one working
                                   });
        return View(model);
    }
```

My method for BigCount is:

```
    public int BigCount(int storeid)
    {
        var big = from t in db.Items
                  where t.StoreID == storeID && t.Size > 100
                  select t;

        return big.Count();
    }
```

CountOfItems displays correctly in view when CountOfBigType() is not shown but once added I get the Linq to Entities error.

Any suggestions please?

Kind regards
Craig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you not be able to simply modify your initial LINQ query as follows and get the same result:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
      var model = db.Stores.OrderBy(s => s.StoreName)
                  .Select (s => new StoreDetails {
                       ID = s.ID,
                       Name = s.StoreName,
                       CountOfItems = s.Items.Count(),
                       CountOfBigType = s.Items.Count(x=>x.Size > 100) <--
                       //other counts if i can get this one working
                       });
      return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: Perfect. I can't VoteUp because I am a lowly "1"!! I would if I could. Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem glad I could help.

Comment: @CraigRoberts You can however make this the accepted answer and you should do so.